# Ansible copy file to specific host based on filename

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy files to a list of hosts and each file has the hostname present in the name. Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: ibank
  become: true
  become_exe: 'sudo su -'
  tasks:
   - name:"copy ibank to {{ inventory_hostname }} qa"
     copy: 
       src: "/usr/local/jenkins_workspace/Trunk_Ibank_Build_Ansible/ibank/DIST/ibank_{{ inventory_hostname }}_qa.war"  
       dest: "/usr/local/ibank/ibank_{{ inventory_hostname }}_qa.war"
     command:
      chdir: /usr/local/ibank
      cmd: /usr/local/ibank/restart.sh
```

But when the file is run I get "ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML. mapping values are not allowed here" 
Not sure what I am doing wrong at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`line 7: column 10      error    syntax error: mapping values are not allowed here (syntax)` you forgot the space  line6 : 
`name: "copy ibank to {{ inventory_hostname }} qa"`

Answer (score 0):

You should move "command" module usage to another task - you can't use 2 modules in one task.

Try something like this:

```
---
- hosts: ibank
  become: true
  become_exe: 'sudo su -'
  tasks:
   - name:"copy ibank to {{ inventory_hostname }} qa"
     copy: 
       src: "/usr/local/jenkins_workspace/Trunk_Ibank_Build_Ansible/ibank/DIST/ibank_{{ inventory_hostname }}_qa.war"  
       dest: "/usr/local/ibank/ibank_{{ inventory_hostname }}_qa.war"
   - name:"restart ibank after copy"
     command:
       chdir: /usr/local/ibank
       cmd: /usr/local/ibank/restart.sh
```